# SUM columnas por Id o cualquier campo en especial en Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Me gustaría agregar algunas columnas para un campo específico y también contar los valores coincidentes. Estaba usando la función Mysql **Over partition by**. Pero descubrí que la **versión 5.7** y superior ya no es compatible. Me gustaría saber si alguien sabe cómo reemplazarlo con alguna nueva actualización e incluso el script como tal. Esta es mi consulta

````
SELECT CAST(A.FechaAsistencia AS DATE) as Fecha, 
       E.Nombre,
       A.Jornada,
       A.TiempoExtra,
       SUM(A.Jornada) OVER (partition BY E.IdEmpleado) AS SumaJornada, 
       E.CostoHora,
       SUM(A.TiempoExtra) OVER (partition BY E.IdEmpleado) AS SumaTiempoExtra,
       E.Sueldo, 
       E.RetSS, 
       E.RetInfonavit, 
       SUM(E.Sueldo) OVER (partition BY E.IdEmpleado) AS SumaSueldo, 
       COUNT(A.Jornada) OVER (partition BY E.IdEmpleado) AS TotalJornada 
FROM tbl_asistencia AS A 
INNER JOIN tbl_empleados AS E 
        ON A.IdEmpleado=E.IdEmpleado 
WHERE EstatusNomina=1 
  AND EstatusImss=1```
````

Comment: No es que `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` sea incompatible con las nuevas versiones de MySQL, sino que desde la versión 8 se introdujo lo que se conoce como window functions. [Revisa el MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), en el tercer bloque de código hay un ejemplo muy parecido a lo que necesitas.